# PHP - Combine arrays with same key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, merge

I have a JSON array of multiple objects, here's an example:

```
$people = [{"name":"John", "color":"green"}, 
           {"name":"Mary", "color":"green"}, 
           {"name":"Bob", "color":"red"}]
```

I use `json_decode($people, true)` to convert them to an array...

Now let's say I want to combine those that have the same `color`. I'd have to do `array_merge_recursive($people[0], $people[1])` because they both have `green` as the `color`. Note that I have to specify which ones I want to merge recursively.

How can I loop through `$people` after it's been decoded to an array format and automatically merge recursively those that have the same key value?

Something like this:

```
foreach($people as $person) {
    // If a person has same color of previous
    // person then merge them recursively.
}
```

So that I could get this after looping:

```
[{"name":"John, Mary", "color":"green, green"}, 
 {"name":"Bob", "color":"red"}]
```

Comment: Use an associative array whose key is the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the result array an associative array keyed by the color.

```
$people_by_color = array();
foreach ($people as $person) {
    if (isset($people_by_color[$person['color']])) {
        $people_by_color[$person['color']]['name'] .= ', ' . $person['name'];
        $people_by_color[$person['color']]['color'] .= ', ' . $person['color'];
    } else {
        $people_by_color[$person['color']] = $person;
    }
}
$people_by_color = array_values($people_by_color); // Turn into indexed array
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! BTW, you missed a parenthesis on the `if` statement. I removed the `color` line  after the `name` because I don't really want to combine two values that are the same, I just figured it would combine them regardless if using `array_merge_recursively`.